# Which is the better convention of declaring pointers in C++? MyClass* ptr (or) MyClass *ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style, declaration

Which is the better convention of declaring pointers in C++?

```
MyClass* ptr
```

(or)

`MyClass *ptr`

I find the first one meaningful, because i feel like declaring MyClass pointer rather than a MyClass and specifying a type modifier. But i see a lot of books recommending the later convention. Can you give the rational behind the convention you follow?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Use what your team uses. If you are working alone, use what you like.

Comment: The real question is whether to use K & R style braces or not...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why

Comment: What Stroustrup has to say: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#whitespace

Comment: This should have been closed as a duplicate, not as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: `MyClass* ptr` is preferred by C++.

Answer (score 6):

The rational behind the convention `MyClass *ptr` is that the `*` belongs to a single variable, so if you have:

`MyClass *ptr1, ptr2`

This declares `ptr2` as a `MyClass`, *not* a `MyClass*`.

Barring the use of this horribly confusing type of declaration, it is a matter of style.